# Quando e como é que "esquisito" adquiriu os significados pejorativos?

Tags: significado, etimologia

*Esquisito*, *exquisite* (inglês), *exquis* (francês) e *exquisito* (espanhol) derivam todos do latim [*exquisitus*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/exquisitus), que significa rebuscado, procurado, escolhido. Mas enquanto em português *esquisito* é usado (quase?) só pejorativamente, os cognatos nas outras três línguas mantiveram significados extremamente apreciativos, mais próximos do significado original no latim:

> Espanhol [*exquisito*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HLo5xx8). De singular y extraordinaria calidad, primor o gusto en su especie.
>
> Francês [*exquis*](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/exquis/32350?q=exquis#32271). Qui est recherché, choisi parmi ce qu'il y a de plus délicat pour le goût. Etc.. (Que é procurado, escolhido entre o que existe de mais delicado para o gosto.)
>
> Inglês [*exquisite*](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/exquisite). Extremely beautiful and very delicately made. Etc.. (Extremamente belo e feito muito primorosamente.)

Nos dicionários, estes significados também são atribuídos ao português [*esquisito*](http://www.aulete.com.br/esquisito), mas estão a meu ver obsoletos. *Esquisito*, pelo menos na minha experiência, é usado só pejorativamente, com o significado de estranho, extravagante, difícil de compreender, ou (acerca de uma pessoa) que não gosta de quase nada.

Não difícil imaginar vias possíveis para a evolução dos significados, mas como e quando é que se deu essa evolução? Quando é que os significados originais de *esquisito* caíram em desuso, e os novos apareceram?

Comment: My experience with "esquisito" in ptBR is that it has no pejorative connotation most of the time.  Let's see some examples 1. O tempo está meio esquisito hoje. (The weather looks strange, we can't tell what it is going to be like)  2. Ele é um cara muito esquisito (he is a most peculiar guy)  3. Isso tudo está muito esquisito (All this looks very odd)  4. Que cheiro esquisito (what a strange odor)   "Esquisito", but right now I can't think of a single sentence where "esquisito" has a pejorative connotation.

Comment: It is just possible that this is one more transatlantic difference between us.   Maybe, with the right intonation, a sentence like "você é muito esquisitão" or "Teu amigo é um cara muito esquisito", might convey it.

Comment: Em todos os teu exemplos, "esquisito" tem um sabor algo pejorativo para mim. Nestes ainda mais: "este vinho tem um sabor esquisito," "sinto-me esquisito hoje." No artigo citado pela Carla, lê-se: "Em nenhum lugar o sentido [de *esquisito*] é pejorativo, o que nos faz pensar que isso é peculiaridade exclusivamente do português." O artigo é brasileiro, portanto parece que também há no Brasil quem ache que *equisito* tem conotação pejorativa.

Comment: @Centaurus: a minha citação do artigo da Carla ficou um bocado esquisita. "Em nenhum lugar" refere-se a nenhum lugar na obra de autores romanos.

Comment: @Centaurus nessas frases, eu entendo "esquisito" como negativo, à semelhança do Jacinto. "Estranho" eu entenderia mais neutralmente, se bem que uma vez me meti em sarilhos por dizer que a comida que alguém cozinhou para mim tinha "um sabor estranho..." que emendei rapidamente (mas não rapidamente que chegue) para "bom mas desconhecido!!"

Comment: @ANeves: Na próxima vez diz "sabor intrigante, curioso, exótico, interessante." Se disseres "diferente" tens que limpar o prato e pedir mais; se não, é duvidoso.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

É possível encontrar uma descrição mais ou menos detalhada da 'trajetória' da palavra 'esquisito' neste excelente artigo do professor Mário Eduardo Viaro.

Em resumo, **a mudança ocorreu na segunda metade do século XIX**, embora antes também seja possível encontrar uma ou outra referência a uma diferente acepção. 
Um exemplo, listado adiante, mostra o uso de ironia para dar significado diferente à palavra, deixando um indicativo de que a ironia possa ter sido um dos mecanismos da mudança semântica.

> **Percurso da ironia**
>
> Consultando o Corpus do Portu­guês,de Mark Davies e Michael J.
>   Ferreira (http://www.corpusdoportugues.com), observa-se que de fato é
>   a segunda metade do século XIX a responsável pela mudança: o novo
>   valor da palavra ocorre já em Machado de Assis (1839-1908), Júlio
>   Dinis (1839-1871), Camilo Castelo Branco (1821-1890), Ramalho Ortigão
>   (1836-1915), embora tenha certa resistência, por exemplo, em Rebelo da
>   Silva (1822-1871) e Júlio Ribeiro (1845-1890). Artur Azevedo
>   (1855-1905), contudo, oscila entre os dois usos.
>
> Contrariamente a essa descoberta, verifica-se que um uso irônico da palavra aparece na correspondência da Marquesa d´Alorna (1750-1839), já em 1809:
>
> “Não foi mais possível ver Dom D. Rodrigo nem falar-lhe, nem respondeu
>   a cartas, nem deu passaportes, nem concluiu nada. Método esquisito de
>   tratar negócios de tanta importância, pois entre gente tão distinta e
>   tão importante, uma decisão, uma resposta favorável ou negativa, poupa
>   tempo, danos e ruínas de fazenda, honra e vida”.
>
> Esse trecho é interessante (aparentemente aí significa apenas
>   “excelente”), pois a ironia é um dos maiores mecanismos de mudança
>   semântica. Eis aí o passo crucial da transformação. Muitas palavras
>   cultas tornam-se populares, pelos mais diversos motivos, mas essa
>   transição nem sempre é tranqüila: uma reviravolta no sentido é
>   importante e comum.

Comment: Muito interessante. Eu só perguntava quando é que o significado mudou, mas afinal o como é que mudou é mais complexo do que eu imaginara. Editei a pergunta para incluir isso também.

Comment: Excelente artigo. Muito obrigado!